# How to do CRUD operations in Firebase with CurrentUserId?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, crud

I'm creating a simple website and i'cant use firebase realtime databases crud operations with currentUserId.

My auth system working good; i can signIn/signUp/signOut on database. And i can write data to firebase with getting inputs from form.

```js
    //GETTING DATA WITH FORM
    
    // Listen for form submit
    document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
    
    
    // Submit form
    function submitForm(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    
      // Get values
      var name = getInputVal('name');
      var sets = getInputVal('sets');
      var reps = getInputVal('reps');
      var weights = getInputVal('weights');
      
      // Write data
      writeData(name, sets, reps, weights);
    
      // Clear form
      document.getElementById('form').reset();
    }
    
    
    // Function to get form values
    function getInputVal(id){
      return document.getElementById(id).value;
    }
    
    
    //CRUD OPERATIONS
    
    // Reference
    var DataRef = firebase.database().ref('users/'  + 'exercises/');
    
    // Write data to database
    function writeData(name, sets, reps, weights){
      var newDataRef = DataRef.push();
      newDataRef.set({
    
        name: name,
        sets: sets,
        reps: reps,
        weights: weights,
        
      });
    }
```

I didn't want to start reading, updating and deleting until I solved this id problem.

So how to do CRUD operations with each users with id? What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking how to write data in a location that is specific to the current user? If so:

```
var currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var DataRef = firebase.database().ref('users/' + currentUser.uid + '/exercises/');
```

Note that this only works if the current user is guaranteed to be already signed in. If you can't guarantee that, put the above code in an [auth state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).