# How to remove data (with prevChildKey) from Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I asked a question before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53868286/how-to-do-crud-operations-in-firebase-with-currentuserid) and I keep going through the same code. I can't figure out how to delete items with prevChildKey.

Console error give this :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteData is not defined
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:1)

**index.html**

```
 <div id="list_div" class="list-div">
   </div>
```

**index.js**

```js
        // Database Reference
            var DataRef = firebase.database().ref('users/' + currentUser.uid + '/exercises/');
    
        // Read data from database
            function readData(){
              //var readDataRef = firebase.database().ref('users/' + currentUser.uid + '/exercises/');    
              DataRef.on("child_added", function(data, prevChildKey) {
                var newData = data.val();
                console.log("ID: " + prevChildKey);
                console.log("name: " + newData.name);
                console.log("sets: " + newData.sets);
                console.log("reps: " + newData.reps);
                console.log("weights: " + newData.weights);
        
                document.getElementById("list_div").innerHTML+=`
                  
                  <div id="listitem_div" class="listitem-div">
                    <span class="listtext">Exercise Name: </span>${newData.name}<br>
                    <span class="listtext">Set: </span>${newData.sets}
                    <span class="listtext">Reps: </span>${newData.reps}
                    <span class="listtext">Weights: </span>${newData.weights}
                    <button type="submit" id="itemremove" class="itemremove"  onclick="deleteData(${prevChildKey})">Delete</button>
                  </div>
                `
              });
            }
                
        //Delete data from database
            function deleteData(prevChildKey){
                var newDataRef = firebase.database().ref('users/' + currentUser.uid + 'exercises/' + prevChildKey);
                  newDataRef.remove()
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The `prevChildKey` you are receiving is not the key of the exercise you want to delete.

Instead use `data.key` to get the id of the exercise and call remove on it.

`console.log("ID: " + data.key);`

Comment: i did try but still nothing happen